# Cannot delete GIT tag because of special character "Ã"

Tags: git, special-characters, git-tag

A tag was created that contains "Ã" in the name, I am unable to delete the tag tried the following:

```
git tag -d -- xxÃxx
git push origin :refs/tags/xxÃxx

git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
git tag -d -- xxÃxx
git push origin :refs/tags/xxÃxx
```

Tried also with double quote for the name.

When executing the commands git says that the tag was deleted:
Local delete:

```
Deleted tag 'xxÃxx' (was 434eae7)
```

After push:

```
remote: warning: Allowing deletion of corrupt ref.
 - [deleted]         xxÃxx
```

Tag "xxÃxx" comes as new at every git fetch -p or git pull(event after two consecutive pulls).

Also tried to delete the tag from source tree but the tag appears again.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: I have no idea what you expect `git -d -- ...` to do - perhaps that should be `git tag -d -- ...`?. Also, `config ...` is probably missing a `git` prefix, otherwise if it does anything, it's not git-related...

Comment: @VonC git version 1.8.4

Comment: @twalberg I've written wrong the command i actually used git tag -d --

Comment: Any chance to try it with a more recent version of Git? (what OS are you using?)

Comment: If it's deleting and it's pushing the deletion remotely, but then it comes back every time you fetch, it's very possible that the problem is on the server side.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1  1.8.4 is the client version and GIT is installed on 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.centos, git version 1.7.1. @VonC do you think that the only solution is to update git ?

Comment: @FlorianStoica As hobb mentions, the issue might be on the server. Check its state when pushing `:refs/tags/xxÃxx`: what does a `git tag` return in the bare repo on the server, after such a push?

Comment: @VonC after such a push the tag is returned with `git tag` command but the special char looks different "▒"

Comment: @FlorianStoica so, on the server, that tag is still visible? Can you try and delete it directly on the server? (`cd /path/to/bare/repo.git; git tag -d -- xxÃxx`)?

Comment: @VonC `error: tag 'xxÃxx' not found.`(connected with cygwin), I've also connected with MINGW32 GIT client through ssh but in this case It wont paste the special character

Comment: Can you try to connect through the more modern bash of git-for-windows? (simply uncompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want, and call git-bash.exe)

Comment: @VonC The result is the same, after deletion, with git pull / fetch the tag comes again as new

Comment: @FlorianStoica and what about a `git clone` (new local clone)?

Comment: @VonC Already tried clone (forgot to write)

Comment: @FlorianStoica I am sure you tried it already, but did you try it after deleting the tag directly on the server? Would then a git clone be more effective?

Comment: @VonC After the clone, the tag is still there but at least it wont come as new tag at any pull/fetch, so I guess this is ok. Even if the tag is not deleted.

Comment: @FlorianStoica And in that new clone, could you try to delete it and push its deletion?

Comment: @VonC in the new clone on delete it says `error: tag 'xxÃxx' not found.`, but `git tag` contains the tag.

Comment: @VonC the tag was not found because on local rep I did not have it I've done a `git push origin :refs/tags/xxÃxx` and it says that it was deleted but `git tag` still contains the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop receiving tag  `'xxÃxx'` as a new tag at every pull/fetch. I've made a clone of the repository.

I did not find a solution on how to actually delete the tag, but this is acceptable for me.

Special thanks to @VonC.

Comment: Glad you made it work in the end (even if it is a workaround). +1

Comment: Happy this is a workaround that works for you, but is not an actual answer to your "how to do delete a tag with a unicode character in it". You shall either change the question or un-mark your answer. The answer is a good answer, just it answer a different quesiton.

Answer (score 4):

In a similar case I used combination of `echo` and `xargs` as follows to delete bad tag containing wrong unicode character `\u0083`:

```
echo -e '\u0083release-1.7.5-hotfix1' |xargs git tag -d
echo -e '\u0083release-1.7.5-hotfix1' |xargs git push --delete origin
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! My tag was displayed as `<U+0096>xxx` (probably a copy-paste from Skype, or one of those other typical Windows problems), and using your command structure `'\u0096xxx'` in git bash enabled me to delete it. IMPORTANT: I would reverse the order of your commands: 1.`push --delete`  2.`tag -d`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably just too stubborn, but I wanted to find a solution that doesn't involve deleting the repo and cloning it again - so here it is.

My bad tag was ◊v2.2.29.

Adding a ref in .git/packed-refs did the trick for me.
Just duplicate (or add) a line in the packed-refs file and change the tag to your problematic one, in the format:

1ea677c29c1db49a284b3a0b44a5e96fda873da2 refs/tags/◊v2.2.29

You don't need to know the real object id for that tag, but you do need a valid one from your project. In my example 1ea677c29c1db49a284b3a0b44a5e96fda873da2 is just an object id of a different tag I had (it doesn't matter which of course - just pick one from a different line in the same file), and the issue is resolved.

Side note:
If you give an object id that doesn't exist at all git will either complain it's invalid or just keep treating it as a new tag, depending on whether you got the structure right or not.

Comment: Thanks for being stubborn but I won't try to replicate in order to fix that again. I had enough head each with it :P

Comment: @FlorianStoica - thanks for the reply. If you want to verify this solution without risking anything you can just clone the repo to a new folder, and then go to the .git/packed-refs at the new folder/clone and remove the line with the bad tag. Then you'll see it's creating the tag on every pull and if you re-add the line to .git/packed-refs it will stop doing it. I verified it myself on a couple of computers as well

Comment: @shuki I'm really unclear as of what you suggest doing in your answer: duplicate a line (any line?), then set the ref to the problematic one (i.e. `refs/tags/◊v2.2.29`) of that duplicated line? Is this correct? Then what to do to delete that tag?